# log(0^0) gives 0 but 0*log(0) gives NaN

Tags: r

When working with loglikelihoods, I sometimes get somethink like:

```
alpha*log(x) # log version of log(x^alpha)
```

In the non-log case, if both `x`  and `alpha` are zero, R assumes 0^0 =1, which is usually the desired behavior (e.g.: the scenario "zero observations that had zero probability" has a probability 1). But in the `alpha*log(x)` version gives NaN:

```
alpha <- 0
x <- 0
log(x^alpha) # gives 0
alpha*log(x) # gives NaN
```

I've read that `0*Inf = NaN` is an IEEE standard, but what are we supposed to do then? Creating a particular case for alpha=0? Not working with logs in this case? Something else?

I guess this is a very common scenario and I wonder how other people deal with it or whether there is some common practice for that.

Comment: By the way, the power rule of log (log(x^alpha=alpha*log(x))is only true if x>0 and the base of log >0 !=1. So for x=0 you cannot apply the rule

Answer (score 5):

R completes algebraic methods in steps, these would be the steps

log(0^0) = log(1) = 0

0 * log(0) = 0 * Inf = ?